# MoveIt keeps repeating planned path trajectory

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a MoveIt configuration package for my robot setup (UR5, Robotiq 2F-85 and workcell).
When launching demo.launch to bring up the robot in RViz I have an issue with trajectory planning.
Everytime I am planning a new trajectory the preview robot (ghosted) keeps repeating its path.
Is there some sort of setting avaiable to limit the amount of planned trajectory iterations?
It makes me kind of dizzy after a while.

I am running ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340250/moveit-keeps-repeating-planned-path-trajectory/) by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is a visualisation setting. Dig into the settings in RViz:

- MotionPlanning

  - Planned path

    - Loop animation

---

Originally posted by [Loy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1830/loy/) with karma: 141 on 2019-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krablander](https://answers.ros.org/users/50137/krablander/) on 2019-12-18**:
Thank you, I think I was scrolling too fast through the settings. This is what I was looking for.